# Read dynamically created elements data attribute in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/amolw/6kdHG/ 
 The buttons are created dynamically (usually the data for buttons will come through AJAX request). For simplicity I've hard coded those values. 
My problem is when i execute this `thisHotel = $(this).data('hname');`
I get undefined in the variable `thisHotel`. 
Same thing happens if i replace the buttons with anchor tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` in your example is the `div id=hotels`. It would have worked if you would have gone INTO the div and selected the button. I propose another solution though.

http://jsfiddle.net/6kdHG/3/

You can use the target of the event to get the information you want.

```
$("[id^='hotel']").on('click', function (e) {
    thisHotel = $(e.target).data('hname');
    $("#selected").html("Selected Hotel " + thisHotel);
});
```

`e` is the event that got triggered and you simply access it's target.

Comment: +1. Or just write a more accurate selector - `$("button[id^='hotel']")`

Comment: Then he would also need delegation since the buttons are added after the DOM is loaded ;)

Comment: Also a good point, but in your solution if I click between the buttons the .data() still returns undefined because I clicked on the div, but still not on a button